# How do I map Ctrl + F8 in vim?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, remapping, urxvt

I've been trying to map Ctrl + F8 in several different ways but I just can't get it to work.
After I made some researches I found out that vim doesn't support all terminal keycodes and I have to assign the terminal keycode to an empty vim keycode (like F13).
I followed [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim) guide step by step without no success.

What i did is:

1. Find the terminal (URxvt) keycode for Ctrl + F8 using cat. The result is: ^[[19^
2. Added the following lines to my plugin file:

`set <F13>=^[[1;2B
 nnoremap <F13> :call foobar`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After testing, I have transferred my comment to an answer.]

Your `set` command is not using the same value as your scancode.  Also, you need to be sure you're using an escape character instead of the two characters of `^` and `[`.  To make this easy without "hard coding" an escape character, I would use `:execute`:

```
:exe "set <F13>=\e[19^"
:nnoremap <F13> :echo "It works!"<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :). Works perfectly fine. However I don't really understand what "\e" means and why ":execute" works and ":set" alone doesn't

Comment: Because, for historical reasons, `:set` cannot have evaluation or string expansion used at all, we get around that with `:execute`.  `\e` in double quotes is a string escape sequence that becomes a true escape character.